# Install pip failed

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip, yum

i am using redhat 5.3

I using following command to update python to 2.7. (it was python 2.4 before update)

```
# xz -d Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
# tar xvf Python-2.7.6.tar
# cd Python-2.7.6/
# ./configure 
# make && make install
```

And I Install the python-setuptools

```
# yum install python-setuptools
```

Then I install the pip print the error

```
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.4.egg/pip/_vendor/colorama/__init__.py", line 2
    from .initialise import init, deinit, reinit
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.4.egg/pip/_vendor/colorama/winterm.py", line 2
    from . import win32
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Adding pip 1.5.6 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/bin
Installing pip2.4 script to /usr/bin

Installed /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.4.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
```

And I run the command pip , it print following errors:

```
# pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.6
```

And I try to uninstall that, it tell me that:

```
[root@linkea-dev-srv1 /]# yum remove pip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository base is listed more than once in the configuration
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: pip
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No Packages marked for removal
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

So I try to reinstall pip by python get-pip.py.
It also has error.

```
# python get-pip.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 17474, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 17466, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 17406, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "/tmp/tmpB9jhvw/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpB9jhvw/pip.zip/pip/log.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpB9jhvw/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/colorama/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpB9jhvw/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/colorama/initialise.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpB9jhvw/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/colorama/ansitowin32.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpB9jhvw/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/colorama/winterm.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpB9jhvw/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/colorama/win32.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: No module named _ctypes
```

Comment: It looks like you're referencing `python` from two different locations: `/usr/lib/python2.4/` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`. So, pip is being installed for python2.4 and not python2.7.

Comment: So how can I do ? @user3689902

Comment: try `yum clean all` then try installing `pip`

Comment: install `pip`, by yum install python-pip, i posted the first comment to clean you yum cache first and then install pip. thats it

Comment: Do not use `yum` to install python stuff if you did not install python itself via yum or a RPM!

Answer (score 8):

You should be very careful when upgrading Python on RedHat (including Fedora/CentOS) because a large majority of the system applications rely on the bundled version of Python.  This is especially true of `yum`, which relies on the version of Python that comes bundled with the operating system.

In short - **if you upgrade the version of Python on RedHat/CentOS/Fedora, yum will not work correctly**.

To install a different version of Python on these distributions, you have two main options. One is to find someone that has released a rpm, download an install that; but you may have to deal with dependencies on your own.

The other (simpler) option is to download the source of Python, compile it and then install it separately (using `altinstall`).

You'll need to install the following packages first:

- `yum groupinstall "Development tools"`
- `yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel`

Next, download the source and extract it. As of this writing, the latest version is 2.7.8:

- `wget "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/Python-2.7.8.xz"`
- `tar xvf Python-2.7.8.xz`
- `cd Python-2.7.8`

Now you have to build and install Python to an alternate location, with the following:

- `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`
- `make && make altinstall`

Once this is done, you'll have `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` available to you.  Next, you'll want to install pip *for this version of Python*. To do that, first install setuptools:

- `wget "https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py"`
- `/usr/local/bin/python2.7 ez_setup.py`
- `/usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7 pip`

The final step is to make sure that this version of Python is available to you.  You can add `/usr/local/bin/` to your `$PATH` by modifying your shell's environment (for example, adding it in `$HOME/.bashrc`); or you can as root create symbolic links in `/usr/bin/` to these utilities. Make sure you give them version-specific tags:

- `ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7`
- `ln -sf /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip2.7`

This will keep your default Python to the system's version (recommended), and then give you the option to use 2.7 when needed.