# Red hat enterprise: pip failed to install package

Tags: python, pip, redhat, paramiko, python-2.6

**The Problem:**
i try to install Paramiko on a red hat enterprise linux server using pip, it works almost except for the last part where it make a error that i can't find a solution on.

A big wall is that the machine run python 2.6.6 and it issn't a option to upgrade this *(the machine are in use and not all scripts are ready for a new python version)*

**I have tried:**
I have tried almost all i could found on the internet:
1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36950894/4691734
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24796817/4691734
3.https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/570ma1/problems_installing_paramiko_on_python_266/

but nothing help, so now i ask all the brains out there for help

**Error code:**

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-61TZZQ/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Y00KLh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-61TZZQ/cffi
```

---

#### Update 1 -- Solution found

Found out a way to fix it, by using `sudo yum`

```
$ sudo yum install pip
```

a little bit weird after that it already installed. But it work

---

I have a little side question about `write()` i'm using a telnet connection and have saved the connection in a var so i can run the follow: `telenet_conn.write()` work in python 2.7 but on 2.6 i mess up, can any tell me why? and how to fix this

Comment: which python's version in your setup ? Also did you tried this [installation (this is working with CentOs and may work with RedHat)](https://davidwzhang.com/2016/09/03/install-python-paramiko-at-centos-7/) ? If not, check this [website and find the right RPM for your OS](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python-paramiko).

Comment: @ChihebNexus Python 2.6.6 If you read all the content you will know ;)

Comment: I looked only at the traceback. But try to look inside the links i gave, maybe you'll solve your question. I use only Debian/Ubuntu OS, i can't help you within my box now.